# Custom tag helper: How do I use complex objects in attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am currently working on an ASP.NET Core custom tag helper. I need to read a complex object from an attribute as follows:

**[Models]**

```cs
public class Page {
  [HtmlAttributeName(page-size)]
  public int size {get; set;}
}

public class MyControl {
  public Page page {get; set;}
}
```

**[TagHelper class]**

```cs
[TargetElement("MyControl", Attributes="page-size")]
public class MyControlTagHelper : TagHelper {
  public Page page {get; set;}
  //Here i have process methods.
}
```

And now I want to get the page size value in the view as follows:

```
<MyControl page-size="4"></MyControl>
```

I don't know to do this. So far, I tried to provide the full complex object to an attribute [as shown in this article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/275/custom-taghelpers-in-asp-net-mvc-6).

How can I read the complex object's values as `page-size`?

Answer (score 7):

Remove the HtmlAttributeName from Page class

```
public class Page {
  public int size{ get;set; }
 }
```

you don't need MyControl class

put the HtmlAttributeName on the PageProperty of your taghelper

```
[TargetElement("MyControl", Attributes="page-info")]
public class MyControlTagHelper : TagHelper {

  [HtmlAttributeName("page-info")]
  public Page page{ get;set; }
 //Here i have process methods.
 }
```

in your view put the markup for your custom tag and pass in the Page object from your viewmodel

```
<MyControl page-info="@Model.Page"></MyControl>
```

now you are passing in the Page object directly on the page-info attribute and you can access its members directly from the process method. Do test it for null inside the process method and if it is null just set output.SuppressOutput(); return;

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i want to get the values for each property in complex object individually. is it possible?

Comment: if you want them individually then you should create properties for each setting on the taghelper and pass them in individually as attributes in your view. You can either pass in a complex object or multiple simple primitive types but you cannot pass in a complex object and have it magically map to separate primitives as far as I know. Seems much cleaner to just pass in the complex object and then access its properties individually like page.size etc

Comment: It works to passing complex object in tag helper (asp net core 2), this answer must be flagged to accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Your tag helper class should be as follows:

```cs
[TargetElement("MyControl", Attributes="page-info")]
public class MyControlTagHelper : TagHelper {

  [HtmlAttributeName("page-info")]
  public Page page {get; set;}
  //Here i have process methods.

}
```

And your view page as follows:

```
<MyControl page-info="new Page{size = 2}"></MyControl>
```

For further reference:

- [`WebsiteInformationTagHelper.cs` source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/2a28e6f4ce80cbbb54acbb0e8f9f9cf6f7f08e1a/test/WebSites/TagHelpersWebSite/TagHelpers/WebsiteInformationTagHelper.cs)
- [`About.cshtml` source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/4bb85eeaeb479edf8abff34e9078886c14d32861/test/WebSites/TagHelpersWebSite/Views/Home/About.cshtml)